# Using Azure Build pipeline log within build

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, checkmarx

I have an Azure build pipeline that runs a Checkmarx scan on a regular basis. Once this runs, the build log is populated with the amount of 'high', 'medium', 'low' severity results are found during the scan. I'd like to access this log to be able to act upon the 'high' severity results found (specifically, I'll be creating an Azure DevOps task).

Is there a way to read the Build log during the actual build? I've found that there is a 'Get Build Log' Azure endpoint but that seems odd to call an endpoint from a build to read its own logs.

Additionally, my first idea was to simply export the Checkmarx results within the Checkmarx step but that doesn't seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to read the Build log during the actual build?

You could use the REST API [Builds - Get Build Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1):

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=5.1
```

Then we could grab the url from the response body to download the last log and parse the log find out the 'high' severity results.

There is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60004185/easily-catch-error-from-maven-install-task-in-build-pipeline-in-azure-devops) about this issue, you could check it for some more info.

Hope this helps.